# Make cursor automatically enter textfield in alertdialog in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make an alertdialog with a textfield and a button. Would like it if each time the alertdialog is called, the textcursor will automatically go into the textfield. Is it possible to do this in flutter?

Comment: use `autofocus` in `TextFormField`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TextField(
   autofocus: true,
)
```

some extra tip to programmatically focus on textfield

```
FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();
TextField(
   focusNode: myFocusNode,
)
```

in where you want to specifically focus the textfield

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);
```